# How to fix ```<function Render.__getattr__.<locals>.template at 0x7f1dafac8400>``` error in python3 web.py

Tags: python-3.x, web.py

I'm using web.py for python3. And gets an error.

Error:

> function Render.**getattr**..template at 0x7fcf15a43840

main.py

```
import web
from web.template import render

urls = (
    '/', 'Home'
)
render = web.template.render('Views/Templates/', base='MainLayout')
app = web.application(urls, globals())

#routes
class Home:
    def GET(self):
        return render.Home

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Views/Templates/MainLayout.html

```
def with (page)

<html>
<head>
  <title> Title </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='app'>
      $:page
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Views/Templates/Home.html

```
<h1> Hello World!</h1>
```

Comment: <function Render.__getattr__.<locals>.template at 0x7fcf15a43840>  error on browser

Comment: render.Home is a function, taking no parameters, so try `render.Home()`